# mongodb $geonear with null coordinates

Tags: mongodb

I want to fetch data sort by $geoNear distance according to lat-long.
problem is that when coordinates are null it does not display data of null entries.

my table structure is described below:
Table: CustomerTasks

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56b82d33435c892b786402fa"), 
"CreatedBy" : ObjectId("56b49e720a351d29b0daaee4"), 
"ModifiedBy" : ObjectId("56b49e720a351d29b0daaee4"), 
"ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-08T05:52:51.107+0000"), 
"TaskText" : "test3", 
"TaskDate" : ISODate("2016-02-11T05:54:50.152+0000"), 
"FromTime" : null, 
"ToTime" : null, 
"AvgSpendTime" : NumberInt(0), 
"MarketingTypeID" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), 
"PromoCode" : null, 
"IsEnquiry" : false, 
"IsAppointment" : false, 
"AppointmentStatusID" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), 
"Location" : null, 
"UserID" : ObjectId("56b49e720a351d29b0daaee4"), 
"IsDeleted" : false, 
"IsCompleted" : false, 
"CustomerSubTaskList" : null, 
"LocationID" : ObjectId("56b9cf531b6687e270432a7b"), 
"Coordinate" : [
    23.008451, 
    72.513027
]}


{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("56b84050435c881e00ed3aab"), 
"CreatedBy" : ObjectId("56b49e720a351d29b0daaee4"), 
"ModifiedBy" : ObjectId("56b49e720a351d29b0daaee4"), 
"ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-02-08T07:14:24.243+0000"), 
"TaskText" : "first", 
"TaskDate" : ISODate("2016-02-10T05:55:13.163+0000"), 
"FromTime" : null, 
"ToTime" : null, 
"AvgSpendTime" : NumberInt(0), 
"MarketingTypeID" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), 
"PromoCode" : null, 
"IsEnquiry" : false, 
"IsAppointment" : false, 
"AppointmentStatusID" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), 
"Location" : null, 
"UserID" : ObjectId("56b49e720a351d29b0daaee4"), 
"IsDeleted" : false, 
"IsCompleted" : false, 
"CustomerSubTaskList" : null, 
"LocationID" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")}
```

my query is:-

```
db.CustomerTasks.aggregate( [
{ $geoNear : { near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [23.0063475,72.5065855] }, distanceField: "distance" ,spherical:true} },  

{ $sort: { "distance": 1 }}] )
```

so, I can not get records which does not contain coordinates.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use  $geoNear, you must first change your document structure to fit a GeoJSON (http://geojson.org/).

Comment: @suecarmol Not true. [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) works just fine with legacy coordinate pair formats, it's just that distance values are returned in "radians" rather than "meters" as it would be with GeoJSON. Howver the question is essentially asking to "mix" both results that are "near" the specified coordinates and results that have no coordinate data at all. This is not possible, and generally is not practical to return in the same results unless there is another sort ranking that should apply to position these elements in results.

Comment: You are absolutely right.